# How to set marker at the top and bottom of a bar in range barchart using chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, charts, chart.js

I'm currently working on a project where I need to create a range bar chart using Chart.js. I've successfully created the range bar chart, but I'm having trouble implementing custom circle markers at the top and bottom of the chart.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- I attempted to create custom markers using Chart.js's `Point` element, but I encountered an error: "Chart.elements.Point is not a constructor".
- I then extended the `Point` element to create a custom point element (`CustomPoint`) and used it to draw the markers. However, the markers are not appearing on the chart as expected.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
    const bottomMarker = myChart.elements.CustomPoint({
      ctx: ctx,
      x: myChart.chartArea.left + myChart.chartArea.width / 2,
      y: myChart.chartArea.bottom,
      options: {
        borderColor: 'blue',
        borderWidth: 2,
        radius: 10,
        backgroundColor: 'white'
      }
    });
    bottomMarker.draw();`
```

Screenshot attached for better understand.
[image]

Comment: How are we supposed to debug your custom point code if you don't provide the code that uses it? Please provide a fully [runnable minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)